# Can we extend the tesseract - ocr library as it is open source?

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am looking for additional functionality that seem unavailable for current version. 
So is it possible for developer community to add functionality or modify existing libraries?

Comment: What license is it released under?

Comment: Whatever you got so far from your research. Please elaborate your question with that information.

Comment: while performing ocr i could see, it is not accurate so can we modify the tesseract classes to make it more accurate